# UITableViewController bottom toolbar does't work?

Tags: objective-c

I have UINavigationController and UITableViewController as root.

```
   myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

   UINavigationController * navContr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

   [self.window addSubview:[navContr view]];
```

I need bottom toolbar with buttons for MyViewController view. Found in google that I should set:

```
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

     if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {

            [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];

     }
     return self;
 }
```

But there is no bottom toolbar in my TableView. What should I do???

Answer (score 0):

Google said that?

Try starting over and make a Tab Bar Controller. http://www.panolee.com/antonimasso/tutorials/tab-bar-application

Then add a TableViewController to it.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need Tab Bar. I need Table View with buttons on the bottom toolbar.